# How do I evenly distribute unique items around the central index location within a list using python?

Tags: python

I am having an issue continuing my workflow. I am using vanilla python to try and sort a list of strings into a certain evenly distributed order.

The input is a given length, which is then divided to gather the number of required unique instances in a list. This list then needs to be sorted as evenly as possible around the list center index.

Input list:
C,C,C,C,C,B,B,AB

Expected output list:
C,B,C,AB,C,B,C,C

I am so stuck, please help!

Code so far:

```
import math

def AddItem(list,item,index):
    result = [] 
    for idx, ele in enumerate(list): 
    # if index multiple of N 
        if idx % index == 0: 
        # extend to append all elements 
            result.extend(item) 
        result.append(ele) 
    return result

lengths = [14421.46,691.99,6992.992,6946.004]
spacings = [8025,3210,1605]

result = []

spacings1 = []
for s in spacings:
    if s == None:
        pass
    else:
        spacings1.append(s)

divisions = []
nums = []

for l in lengths:
    pack = []
    for s in spacings1:
        n = math.ceil(l/s)
        if n < 1:
            r = 1
        else:
            r = n
        pack.append(r)
    nums.append(pack)

for p in nums:
    types = []
    l_num = p[0]
    for x in xrange(l_num):
        types.append("AB")
    t_num = p[1]-p[0]
    for x in xrange(t_num):
        types.append("B")
    try:
        g_num = p[2]
        for x in xrange(g_num):
            types.append("C")
    except:
        pass
    
    result.append(types)
    
OUT = result
```

Comment: Does the initial order of the list matter at all for the final output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evenly divide 1 by the number of each unique item plus one to get a fraction for that item and slot the items into multiples of the fraction so the resulting multiples can be used as keys for sorting:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

lst = ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'AB']
print(
    list(
        map(
            itemgetter(1),
            sorted(
                ((i + 1) / (count + 1), item)
                for item, count in Counter(lst).items()
                for i in range(count)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This outputs:

```
['C', 'B', 'C', 'AB', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C']
```